# Why is my command-line hash different from online MD5 hash results?

Tags: command-line, hashing

On a [Mac OS X v10.5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Leopard) (Leopard) PowerPC, if I do:

```
echo "hello" | md5
```

on the command line, the result is:

```
b1946ac92492d2347c6235b4d2611184
```

But if I enter hello into one of the online MD5 hash sites like http://md5online.net/, I get:

```
5d41402abc4b2a76b9719d911017c592
```

Am I doing something wrong? If I want to use MD5 on the go, how can I make sure what I'm getting on the command line will agree with the online md5 tools?

Comment: Works for me on Windows with Total Commander creating the MD5 checksum. Same as the online version.

Comment: Thanks, Snark. Rudedog solved the problem when using md5 on the command line, at least for POSIX systems. Give him a +1 if you can. I'm too new.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

When you echo from the command line, md5 is calculating the sum of 6 characters - h,e,l,l,o plus newline. The text you enter in a website doesn't have a newline.

Try doing

```
echo -n hello | md5
```

and it'll give you what you expect. The -n tells echo not to output a newline.

Comment: Oops. I didn't notice the '-n' tag. You're right Rudedog. That worked. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Rudedog your answer from 12 years ago just saved my sanity!

Answer (score 5):

You can also use printf instead of echo, which automatically suppresses the newline character:

```
printf hello | md5
```

Or even:

```
printf "hello" | md5
```

Answer (score 1):

b1946ac92492d2347c6235b4d2611184 ist the md5 of just the string

```
hello
```

5d41402abc4b2a76b9719d911017c592 ist the md5 of

`hello`

CR+LF

CR+LF is the Windows newline.

Comment: -1. Totally mixed up. Sole `hello` gives `5d…`; `hello`LF gives `b1…`; `hello`CRLF gives `af5597c29467a96523a70787c319f4db`.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you call (OSx), bash and zsh add newline character by default.

```
echo "123" | md5
```

ba1f2511fc30423bdbb183fe33f3dd0f

---

```
echo "123" | tr -d "\n" | md5
```

202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70

```
echo -n "123" | md5
```

202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70

```
printf "123" | md5
```

202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70