# Inconsistencies on MD5 checksums

Tags: shell, hashing, echo

I am trying to obtain the md5 hash of a string. Said string consists of only uppercase and lowercase letters and digits. No other characters, including spaces and newlines. The string is inputted  via a keyboard, rather than a file input, so there's no BOM or other flags present.

If I run locally using `md5sum` I get the following output:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ echo word | md5sum 
a46ec67a0f2e7c387926ac5d783ea4b8 - 

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ echo "word" | md5sum
a46ec67a0f2e7c387926ac5d783ea4b8  - 

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ echo "word" -n | md5sum
3a21ca21563e9535a9012daef61a0bdf  -
```

<del>I know the difference between the 2nd and 3rd outputs above [is due to the absence of the newline character](https://superuser.com/a/71555/165442) (`-n`). **This part is clear to me**</del>. (Turns out it was not! See the accepted answer.)

However, there are tools that give a third result. All non-CLI tools seems to give *the same* result, and that is what confuses me:

- http://www.miraclesalad.com/webtools/md5.php says it's `c47d187067c6cf953245f128b5fde62a`.
- http://www.md5hashgenerator.com/ says it's `c47d187067c6cf953245f128b5fde62a`.
- http://www.md5.cz/ says it's `c47d187067c6cf953245f128b5fde62a`.
- http://www.md5online.org/md5-encrypt.html says it's `c47d187067c6cf953245f128b5fde62a`.
- http://md5-hash-online.waraxe.us/ says it's `c47d187067c6cf953245f128b5fde62a`.
- [This Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.md5hash) says it's `c47d187067c6cf953245f128b5fde62a`.
- `echo -n "word" | unix2dos | md5sum` gives me `c47d187067c6cf953245f128b5fde62a`.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ echo "word" -n | md5sum
3a21ca21563e9535a9012daef61a0bdf  -
$ echo "word -n" | md5sum
3a21ca21563e9535a9012daef61a0bdf  -
$ echo "-n" word | md5sum
c47d187067c6cf953245f128b5fde62a  -
```

Specifically, note that:

```
$ echo "word" -n
word -n
```

All options must come before non-option arguments. This is the case in most programs except some GNU utilities, and is the case in all implementation of `echo` (`echo` is special however in that most strings beginning with `-` are interpreted as arguments, only a few options are recognized as such).

Comment: A better example might be to just show the output of `echo "word" -n`. Pretty clear why its failing when you see that!