# The MD5 hash value is different from Bash and PHP

Tags: linux, bash, security, php, md5sum

I tried to generate the [MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) sum (using md5sum) of a string, "hello". I tried out different methods as the md5sum tool in Linux, PHP's MD5() function as well as various online text to md5sum translators.

```
echo "hello" | md5sum
```

and

```
echo "hello" > file && md5sum file
```

Gave the result `b1946ac92492d2347c6235b4d2611184`. However, PHP's md5() function and almost all online generators gave the output `5D41402ABC4B2A76B9719D911017C592`.

What is the reason?

Comment: echo -n "hello"

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/71554/md5-why-is-my-command-line-hash-different-from-online-md5-hash-results

Answer (score 87, accepted):

By default, `echo` includes a newline character at the end of the output. However, PHP and the online sites you used do not include the newline. To suppress the newline character, use the `-n` flag:

```
echo -n "hello" | md5sum
```

Output:

```
5d41402abc4b2a76b9719d911017c592  -
```

See: `help echo`

---

or with printf:

```
printf "%s" "hello" | md5sum
```

Comment: I would suggest showing the more widely compatible form *before* the one that relies on behavior unspecified by POSIX.

Comment: Thank you. I prefer to show the problem first with his own example and the behavior of echo.

Comment: Unless you know the OP's operating system, you don't know that the modified version of "their own example" will actually work. `echo -n` could echo `-n` if their Linux is using a stripped-down Busybox.

Comment: I know OP's operating system.

Comment: They specify their kernel, but where do they say more than that?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Good catch.

Comment: what about the extra ``` -``` at the end?

Comment: @lrkwz: I assume that means the data came from [stdin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_.28stdin.29) and not from a file.

Answer (score 100):

@Cyrus's answer is exactly on point with how to resolve this - to explain, when using `echo` it will output a newline at the end of the string. As you can see on this online output, `hello` with a newline outputs exactly the MD5 you were getting previously. Using `-n` suppresses the newline, and will then give you the result you expected.

[image]

**Edit**:

You can see it clearly if you output it to `hexdump`, which shows the hexadecimal of the bytes there.

```
$ echo "str_example" | hd
00000000  73 74 72 5f 65 78 61 6d  70 6c 65 0a              |str_example.|
```

See the `0a` (`\n`) in the end of the string

```
$ echo -n "str_example" | hd
00000000  73 74 72 5f 65 78 61 6d  70 6c 65                 |str_example|
```

With `-n` echo doesn't put a new line (`\n`) in the end

Now with a empty string

```
$ echo  "" | hd
00000000  0a                                                |.|
```

Just the New Line character

```
$ echo -n  "" | hd
```

Empty string, so `hexdump` shows no output

Comment: Would be more interesting to pipe `echo hello` and `echo -n hello` to `hexdump -C` respectively ;)

Comment: I recommend against `echo -n`, since it's nonstandard and inconsistently supported (see [the Single Unix Spec for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/echo.html) and a [more detailed catalog of incompatibilities by Sven Mascheck](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/echo+printf/)). In you want it to work consistently, use `printf` instead; it's a bit more complex to use (you have to specify a format string in addition to the data you want printed), but IMO worth it to avoid trouble. In this case, `printf "%s" "hello"` will do the trick.