# Why do I get different results from Mac's shasum than from other shasum calculators?

Tags: macos, console, checksum

I'm entering:

```
appletree:~ somename$ shasum -a 512 <<< test
```

And the output is:

```
0e3e75234abc68f4378a86b3f4b32a198ba301845b0cd6e50106e874345700cc6663a86c1ea125dc5e92be17c98f9a0f85ca9d5f595db2012f7cc3571945c123  -
```

Then I go to some online hash generators and enter "test" too. Their answers are:

http://hashgenerator.de/:

```
ee26b0dd4af7e749aa1a8ee3c10ae9923f618980772e473f8819a5d4940e0db27ac185f8a0e1d5f84f88bc887fd67b143732c304cc5fa9ad8e6f57f50028a8ff
```

http://passwordsgenerator.net/sha512-hash-generator/:

```
EE26B0DD4AF7E749AA1A8EE3C10AE9923F618980772E473F8819A5D4940E0DB27AC185F8A0E1D5F84F88BC887FD67B143732C304CC5FA9AD8E6F57F50028A8FF
```

So the online generators agree. What am I missing in the Mac console command?

I was reading the `man` pages. I see it's implemented using a Perl library. However, I think sha512 would be a unique designation, so I have to dig deeper.

---

There seems to be a duplicate question: [Why is my command-line hash different from online MD5 hash results?](https://superuser.com/q/71554/681288). While the other question is in the same context, which is unexpected whitespace, it emerges from a different situation.

- `<<<` is a [here string](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80362/what-does-mean), and there is a [design choice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20157/why-does-a-bash-here-string-add-a-trailing-newline-char) for how here strings add newline.
- `echo 'bla' |` means piping, which invokes sub shells, and also has arguments for how to handle newline. Here it seems you have to consider the [shell version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11193466/818827).

Comment: Thanks a lot to sideshowbarker and Spiff. Whitespace strikes again ^^ ^^

Comment: Possible duplicate of [md5: Why is my command-line hash different from online md5 hash results?](http://superuser.com/questions/71554/md5-why-is-my-command-line-hash-different-from-online-md5-hash-results)

Comment: Note that a here string is intended to be exactly identical to a one-line here document, and a here document always ends with a newline.

Comment: I am not new to shell, but here are some sophisticated details and news for which I'm grateful. So thanks for all the comments and answers.

Comment: So we found that Mac's shasum command isn't any different. The issue was technically user error, and had to do with the data being passed, not the program.  May I suggest renaming the question, to "Why do I get different results from Mac's shasum..." That way, people can instantly suspect a user-created issue.  (Had I seen that, I might have been less inclined to check this question out right now. As currently titled, "What distribuishes the mac shell shasum from other shasum calculators?", I came here to learn about possible Mac-specific differences, which isn't what this actually ended up as

Comment: @TOOGAM: I agree, so I altered the title. Thanks a lot for the suggestion.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The input to the `shasum` invocation in the question is `test\n` (with a newline), not `test`.

If you give `test` with no newline to `shasum` you’ll get the same output as the online tools cited:

```
$ echo -n "test" | shasum -a 512
ee26b0dd4af7e749aa1a8ee3c10ae9923f618980772e473f8819a5d4940e0db27ac185f8a0e1d5f84f88bc887fd67b143732c304cc5fa9ad8e6f57f50028a8ff  -
```

By the way, I think there’s nothing MacOS-specific about the `shasum` found on MacOS; I think `shasum` is part of the standard Perl distro — installed along with, e.g., the `perl` command.

Comment: You the real MVP. Had me stumped for quite awhile, assuming that I was doing something clearly wrong. Turns out `echo` is just doing some sneaky newline business.

Answer (score 20):

Try this:

```
hexdump -C <<< test
```

Knowing Unix shells, you're probably getting an unwanted 0x0a at the end of that string.

Comment: `od` will label control characters and make the more apparent; try: 
`od  -t a -t x1 <<< test`
(never really used hexdump),